# ViewControllers are not destructing

Tags: ios, swift, memory, hierarchy

I've got a serious problem with my iOS app.

I have a login logic in my application. When logging in and then logging out, some view controllers are not destructing. This causes some issues, for example, some events that I emit using `NSNotifcationCenter` are emitted few times. These issues are avoidable, but I really want a solution to avoid some view controllers to stay open in the background without me controlling it.

The way control the login logic is as follows:

In the app delegate start function, if the user is already logged in, I set the root view controller to the main usable view controller. Therefore, I'm not doing anything and the root view controller is set to the login view controller navigation controller through the storyboard.

When the user logs off, I use a modal segue to transition the view controller back to the login view controller navigation controller.

As you may understand I'm using storyboards, swift and the newest iOS.

My logout code is segue that take me to the LoginViewControler:

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Logout", sender: self)
```

My app delegate code:

```
if (userDefaults.valueForKey("uid") != nil) {
    let tabBarView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TabBarViewController") as! TabBarViewController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = tabBarView        
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

I would appreciate help :)

**EDIT**

I even tried just setting the root view controller in the logout action and that didn’t help either. How’s that even possible?

This is how I do the logout now:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let newRootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginNavigationController") as! UINavigationController          

appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = newRootViewController
```

Comment: When you logout, What is your window's root View Controller? You are not resetting it maybe and window is keeping the VC alive.

Comment: As here is login functionality you should do requests to backend. Could you please post this code to your question? it can be problem with retain count in this piece of code.

Comment: I am afraid there is not enough information. This is a problem with memory leaks, they can be caused anywhere. It's very hard to find a memory leak from a few pieces of code. The controller can prevent itself from deallocating with some closure, for example.

Comment: I want to understand who likes to downvote all people just for fun without motivate with a comment, SO promotes who puts positive votes, not the opposite attitude.

Comment: Can you please share a class which you are sure about not deallocating...

Comment: Down voted for what? No comment for the down vote. These kind of actions discourage people from offering you help. Obviously, down voting for all answers - makes me wonder if this is the author of this question... Anyway, I still think you're abusing Apple's API and you should consider changing your code. Good luck.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano Alessandro, I can only suggest you guys do the same as I just did - upvote every answer that was down-voted by this dude.

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano not sure if it is, but I think it's not ok to down vote an answer that someone has worked for without explaining why.

Comment: @devdc I think exactly like you but sometime in SO there is a bad attitude, there are many Stack Exchange questions that discuss about downvoting and the possible obligation to comment,
maybe it will be a future option

Answer (score 2):

Adam H. is right. If that doesn't work, then check for IBOutlets and delegates that have strong relationships, and change them to weak relationships. i.e.

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Without the weak keyword the view controller will never be disposed.

Depending on how your project is setup, if you are using a navigation controller (which I recommend) every time someone logs out you would put

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.navigationController.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

That will pop everything off the navigation stack, which will dispose of all view controllers (unless you have strong relations, then they won't be disposed)

Comment: first, I made sure all outlets have the weak keyword. second, I don’t use navigation controller for this transition.

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: @IBOutlet is a weak by default. May be there are other properties that should be weak, but it's not IBOutlets.

Comment: @anatoliy_v IBOutlets are weak by default when Xcode adds them in for you, but if you type it out and link it to the storyboard it might not be weak.

Comment: My vcs are programmatic so setting my objects to weak var didn't work for out for me but his 2nd answer did. My problem was actually 2 twofold. I had to declare [weak self] inside the closure of some uialertview actions I had and I followed this guy's which was to call navigationController?.popViewController. I didn;t have to put it on the main queue but it worked and my vc was deallocated.

Answer (score 2):

No matter how you choose to manage your trasitions  , don't forget to add/ remove the observer whenever the view controller apear/disappear.

Comment: I want some of the events to still work when the view is not appearing. So,this doesn’t help.

Answer (score 1):

If the **logged in** screen presents the **login** screen and the **login** screen presents the **logged in** screen then you will have a cycle that keeps piling on new view controllers. To solve this, one must not present the other, but unwind to it. Another possibility is to hold instances of each as singletons and only present those.

Comment: I’ve just tried using unwind segue to transition from the main view to the login view, but that didn’t solve the issue. Any ideas ,singletons might be an idea what then ill have to write some code to clean the class, in what way do i do this?

Comment: If you are using an unwind segue to get from the main view to the login view then there should be one instance of the login view and a new instance of the main view should be created each time. Make sure this is the case. It is possible you are not properly unwinding. At any given time, there should be no more than one of each.

Comment: unwind doesn’t help in my situation because my main view controller is not under a navigation controller

Comment: The main point is that you should not add on a view controller to go back to a previous screen. If you are not using a navigation controller then call `dismissViewController`.

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 1):

I implemented something like that not long ago and to me it seems you're abusing the UINavigationController life cycle.
After reading your question twice, if I understand it correctly, it seems you're initializing your login view controller as a UINavigationController which stacks-up view controllers. Once user logs out, you're keeping the stack, adding more ViewControllers to the stack using the performSegue. 
You can avoid it by using two different scenes -
1) Login View Controller which stands by it self.
2) Main flow of your app - can start with UITabController/ UINavigationController, both or whatever.

In AppDelegate you check -
If user is logged in - do your logics and set the app rootVC to the main flow vc.
Otherwise you set the loginVC (UIViewController) to be the root.

This also allows you to pop the login VC anywhere in the main flow, when needed, without interfering with the main flow.
In your case the loginVC is always UINavigationController's root so you must popToRootVC every time you wish to see it or performSegue to it which is worse because then you create another instance of a UINavigationController and resources never get deallocated.

Obviously in programming, in most cases, there are many solutions to one problem. I'm sure your problem can be solved using your flow. I just think it's bad experience to stack a loginVC over a navigation controller.

Comment: Down voted for what? No comment for the down vote. These kind of actions discourage people from offering you help. Obviously, down voting for all answers - makes me wonder if this is the author of this question...
Anyway, I still think you're abusing Apple's API and you should consider changing your code. 
Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that setting a new `rootViewController` on the `UIWindow` doesn't remove the view hierarchy from the old root view controller. That leaves all sorts of strong references hanging around, and if you use Xcode's view debugging, you can see that the the old view hierarchy is still sitting there, behind the new `rootViewController`'s view hierarchy.

Something like this should fix the problem for you and allow your view controllers to deinit:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let newRootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginNavigationController") as! UINavigationController          

appDelegate.window??.rootViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
appDelegate.window??.rootViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
appDelegate.window??.rootViewController = newRootViewController
```

Comment: @gal  Sorry, that solution assumed there was a modal presentation happening in the current root view controller. I updated the answer slightly, and it works for me in various similar cases. Would you mind giving that a try?

Comment: @gal  Why don't you post your project somewhere so we can take a look at it?  It's quite likely the problem may not be where you are looking or related to the information you are providing in your question.

Answer (score 1):

get rid of ARC file by file in build settings or wholesale
per project (it seems that you can have non ARC project but have weak references
while at it: not sporting I suppose but you can have both).

Then override retain and release in the problematic view controller
and see who hold the extra reference by breaking in the overriden
retain and release. It should be an eduficational experience.

The lazy approach is to kill ARC just for the VC in question.

I'd be curious to see how this works for VCs written in swift ;-)

Me thinks it's yet another reason to stay in objc domicile a while longer
until/if swift compiler and runtime solidifies (if ever).

Hope this helps anyone.

PS: It takes forever to compile some swift file in my project and I have NO
idea which swift file is causing this. Duh.

Answer (score 1):

As yet indicated there aren't a lot informations for provide correctly the solution to your question.
I can suggest you to change your approach. I made a similar workflow using a `UINavigationController` (navigationController) launched from AppDelegate, inside of if we are logged in I put as ViewControllers :

(where **self** is `navigationController` and **rootViewController** is another `UINavigationController`)

```
self.setViewControllers[loginViewController, rootViewController]
```

If your are not logged in you put only loginViewController:

```
self.setViewControllers[loginViewController]
```

in this case you can put the `rootViewController` where the user is logged in.
This is my 2cent.

Answer (score 1):

I like having a **root VC** which is just blank. When the app starts, root VC immediately displays **login VC** as a child VC of root VC. When the user successfully authenticates, the login VC notifies root VC, which then adds **main VC** as a child of root VC, *transitions* (with a nice animation) from login VC to main VC (using `[self transitionFromViewController: toViewController: duration: options: animations: completion:]`), and then removes login VC as a child and discards it. On logout, main VC notifies root VC which then does the same thing in reverse. So most of the time you only have either login VC or main VC instantiated; the only time they are both instantiated is during the transition.

I find segues are useful for building quick prototypes, but for production apps I prefer not to use them.

Comment: You're using downvotes incorrectly. You should upvote answers you find helpful, and leave the rest alone unless they are sloppy or dangerous. http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: I can only suggest you do the same I did and up-vote every answer that was down voted by this dude.

Answer (score 1):

I Guess the ViewControllers Stack of you will go like this:
- 1st launch: LoginVC
- After login: LoginVC - TabarVC
- Click Logout: LoginVC - TabarVC - LoginVC
....

So your below code should work:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let newRootViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginNavigationController") as! UINavigationController          

appDelegate.window!.rootViewController = newRootViewController
```

but it's not:(. In my opinion, You should always let the tabarVC   rootViewController. And check in TabarVC, if user is not loged-in or user pressed logout, Present loginVC and dismiss it instead of performSegue.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove your :

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Logout", sender: self)
```

Instead of it, you can overriding this **segue** method, this is enough:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("uid") 
        if segue.identifier == "Logout" {
            let newRootViewController = segue.destinationViewController
            // newRootViewController is optional in case you want to pass vars
            // do whatever you want with your newRootViewController
        }
}
```

About your `NSNotification` there are two methods to remove it:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "NotificationIdentifier", object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self) // Remove from all notifications being observed
```

In Swift, you can put the removeObservers in the new and special `deinit` [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html).

[image]

Comment: This  procedure work well on a Xcode project test,  please motivate downvote